# @NumberFormat accepts comma and dot, how to achieve this in InitBinder

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

If I annotate a command object field like this, fractional numbers with comma and dot will both be validated and bound correctly (which I want):

```
@NumberFormat(style=Style.NUMBER)
private Double amount;
```

However, annotating a collection with `@NumberFormat` the same way doesn't work, so I'm trying to reproduce this behavior in a global `InitBinder`:

```
@InitBinder
public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    binder.addCustomFormatter(new NumberStyleFormatter()); 
}
```

but it still accepts comma only.

Spring's annotation processor code seems to do the same, yet they accept both comma and dot. What am I missing?

```
public class NumberFormatAnnotationFormatterFactory extends EmbeddedValueResolutionSupport
        implements AnnotationFormatterFactory<NumberFormat> {

    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getFieldTypes() {
        return NumberUtils.STANDARD_NUMBER_TYPES;
    }

    @Override
    public Printer<Number> getPrinter(NumberFormat annotation, Class<?> fieldType) {
        return configureFormatterFrom(annotation);
    }

    @Override
    public Parser<Number> getParser(NumberFormat annotation, Class<?> fieldType) {
        return configureFormatterFrom(annotation);
    }


    private Formatter<Number> configureFormatterFrom(NumberFormat annotation) {
        if (StringUtils.hasLength(annotation.pattern())) {
            return new NumberStyleFormatter(resolveEmbeddedValue(annotation.pattern()));
        }
        else {
            Style style = annotation.style();
            if (style == Style.CURRENCY) {
                return new CurrencyStyleFormatter();
            }
            else if (style == Style.PERCENT) {
                return new PercentStyleFormatter();
            }
            else {
                return new NumberStyleFormatter(); // THIS CASE
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Use pattern.

[NumberStyleFormatter](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/format/number/NumberStyleFormatter.html#NumberStyleFormatter-java.lang.String-) provides `setPattern` method to which you can set the pattern(regex).

```
@InitBinder
public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
     binder.addCustomFormatter(new NumberStyleFormatter(String pattern)); 
}
```

**Update:** Regex to accept both comma and dot `^[0-9.,]+$`.

```
   System.out.println("50,000.25".matches("^[0-9.,]+$")); //true
```

Comment: I don't think you can set a pattern that accepts both comma and dot at the same time.

Comment: which means something like `50,000.25`?

Comment: Patter that accepts both comma and dot=> `^[0-9.,]+$`

Comment: True, but for NumberStyleFormatter, `DecimalFormat.applyPattern` is used, which doesn't accept a regex. I will probably need to implement a custom formatter, but still perplexed how Spring achieves this without doing that.

Comment: Even `DecimalFormat.applyPattern` provides pattern to do that...[check this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html?is-external=true#applyPattern-java.lang.String-)

Comment: I ended up using a custom Formatter that replaces the comma with a dot before attempting parsing. Checked applyPattern that you suggested but still not see how to specify two different decimal points.